# Finding size of largest connected component of a graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

Consider we have a random undirected graph G = (V,E) with n vertices, now suppose for any two vertices u and v ∈ V, the probability that the edge between u and v ∈ E is 1/n. We need to figure out the size of the largest connected component in the undirected graph C(n).
C(n) should be equal to Θ(n**a), we need to run some experiments to give an estimate of a.

I am a bit confused on how to link the probability 1/n to the largest connected component, is there any way I can do so?

Comment: The question is somewhat vague. Does E contian all edges or just some?(assuming some). So your task is to find the longest connected path? Then dijkstra with some extra variable would be your best bet

Comment: E contains all edges of the graph

Comment: Let me edit a little

Comment: How are the vertices stored? I am thinking of doing DFS/BFS on a vertex in the list. If any vertices are left do DFS/BFS on one from that list. Keep doing this. Each distinct DFS/BFS is a component. Count vertices in component. However, your questions states O(n^a) where a should be determined by experiment. My assumption is then that you have to do DFS/BFS on each vertex you have to determine the largest component. This results in O(n^n)

Comment: Oh thanks so much, I think I have an idea now.

Answer (score 0):

The process you're simulating here is called the [Erdős–Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model). You have a collection of n nodes, and each pair of nodes has probability p of being linked. The (expected) shape of the resulting graph depends heavily on the choice of p, and there are a lot of famous results about this.

As for how to do this: one option would be to create a collection of n nodes, iterate over all pairs of nodes, and link them with probability 1/n. You can then run an algorithm like BFS or DFS over the graph to find and size the connected components.

Another would be to use the above approach, except that instead of doing a BFS or DFS to use a [disjoint-set forest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure) to perform the links and find the largest connected component.

Alternatively, because each edge is absent or present with equal probability and independently of every other edge, the number of edges you have is [binomially distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution) and pretty tightly packed around n total edges. You could therefore generate n random edges, add them into the graph, then use the above techniques. (This will be much faster, as this does O(n) work rather than O(n<sup>2</sup>) work to process the edges.)

Once you've gotten this worked out, you can vary n over a large range and run some sort of polynomial regression on it to find the best-first curve. That's something you could either code up yourself, or which you could do by importing your data into Excel and using its regression tools.

As a spoiler, when you're done you'll find that the number of nodes in the largest connected component is **Θ(n<sup>2/3</sup>)**. If you search for "Erdős–Rényi critical case," you can find online proofs of this result. It's not a trivial result to prove (and definitely isn't obvious!), but it'll drop out of your empirical analysis.